# How to remove several rows in a Spark Dataframe based on the position (not value)?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I want to do some data preprocessing using pyspark and want to remove data at the begining and end of data in dataframe. Let's say I want the first 30% and last 30% data to be removed. I only find possibilities based on values using `where` and find the `first` and the `last` but not for several. Here is the basic example so far with no solution:

```
import pandas as pd
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("foo").getOrCreate()
cut_factor_start = 0.3 # factor to cut the beginning of the data
cut_factor_stop = 1-cut_factor_start # factor to cut the end of the data
# create pandas dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame({'part':['foo','foo','foo','foo','foo', 'foo'], 'values':[9,1,2,2,6,9]})
# convert to spark dataframe
df = spark.createDataFrame(df)
df.show()
```

> ```
> +----+------+
> |part|values|
> +----+------+
> | foo|     9|
> | foo|     1|
> | foo|     2|
> | foo|     2|
> | foo|     6|
> | foo|     9|
> +----+------+
> ```

```
df_length  = df.count()
print('length of df: ' + str(df_length))
cut_start = round(df_length * cut_factor_start)
print('start postion to cut: ' + str(cut_start))
cut_stop  = round(df_length * (cut_factor_stop))
print('stop  postion to cut: ' + str(cut_stop))
```

> ```
> length of df: 6
> start postion to cut: 2
> stop  postion to cut: 4
> ```

What I want it based on the calculations:

> ```
> +----+------+
> |part|values|
> +----+------+
> | foo|     1|
> | foo|     2|
> | foo|     2|
> +----+------+
> ```

Comment: you can use windows function of row_number using which you will the get the current row number which you can then use in filter clause to remove

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another way is using `between` after assigning a row_number:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
from pyspark.sql import Window

rnum= F.row_number().over(Window.orderBy(F.lit(0)))
output = (df.withColumn('Rnum',rnum)
        .filter(F.col("Rnum").between(cut_start, cut_stop)).drop('Rnum'))
```

---

```
output.show()

+----+------+
|part|values|
+----+------+
| foo|     1|
| foo|     2|
| foo|     2|
+----+------+
```

Answer (score 0):

On Scala, unique "id" column can be added, and then "limit" and "except" functions:

```
val dfWithIds = df.withColumn("uniqueId", monotonically_increasing_id())
dfWithIds
  .limit(stopPostionToCut)
  .except(dfWithIds.limit(startPostionToCut - 1))
  .drop("uniqueId")
```